# Create a new column in a spatial dataframe from existing columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a shapefile uploaded as a`dataframe` in `R` in which two of the columns are `X1` and `X5`, and from these two columns, I am creating a new column `class` using `dplyr`. The code sort of works, but there are `NA` values in the new column, where there were suppose to be `X1` values. How can this be fixed?

Sample data with columns of interest

```
FID X1  X5  class
1   VEG PRPU    
2   VEG PRPU    
3   VEG PRPU    
4   VEG PRPU    
5   WTR NA  
6   WTR NA  
7   WTR NA  
8   VEG PLSE    
9   VEG PLSE    
10  GRND NA         
11  GRND NA
```

Data type information using `str(df)`

```
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  211 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ id      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X1      : chr  "VEG" "VEG" "VEG" "VEG" ...
 $ X2      : chr  "GRN" "GRN" "GRN" "GRN" ...
 $ X3      : chr  "SHRB" "SHRB" "SHRB" "SHRB" ...
 $ X4      : chr  "DES" "DES" "DES" "DES" ...
 $ X5      : chr  "PLSE" "PLSE" "PLSE" "PLSE" ...
 $ geometry:sfc_POLYGON of length 211; first list element: List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:7, 1:2] 756524 756524 756524 756524 756524 ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "POLYGON" "sfg"
 $ class   : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "id" "X1" "X2" "X3" ...
```

Code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
# Create a new column `class`
df = st_read("/path", "file")
df = df%>% add_column(class = NA)

# Mutate
df = df %>% dplyr::mutate(class = ifelse(X5 == "", X1, X5))
```

Updated spatial dataframe

```
  FID   X1  X5  class
    1   VEG PRPU PRPU   
    2   VEG PRPU PRPU
    3   VEG PRPU PRPU   
    4   VEG PRPU PRPU   
    5   WTR NA   NA
    6   WTR NA   NA
    7   WTR NA   NA
    8   VEG PLSE PLSE
    9   VEG PLSE PLSE   
    10  GRND NA  NA
    11  GRND NA  NA
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from your data but could there be a space issue in the X5 column? I.e. `" " =/= ""`.  You might try stripping whitespace off i.e. `str_trim()` or even try `coalesce` with X1 as the second argument.

Comment: Can you please share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) such as a with a `dput()`? It's unclear exactly what you're working with.

Comment: `dput(df)` is creating a very long output, should I still paste it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were `NA` values in the column `X5` which are not exactly empty cells (as shown in `ArcGIS`). I had to slightly adjust the code, and now it works.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
# Create a new column `class`
df = st_read("/path", "file")
df = df%>% add_column(class = NA)

# Mutate
df = df %>% dplyr::mutate(class = ifelse(is.na(X5), X1, X5))
```

Comment: `df = df %>% dplyr::mutate(class = coalesce(X5, X1))` should works as well.